# Angular JS: To get the scope value outside the http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, function, closures

I have multiple select boxes. For each of these select boxes the http call has diffrent URL. I need to load the response data into these boxes:

```js
function getFilterDataUrl(category_url) {
  var filterUrl = Config.endpoints.getMilestoneFilter.url+"?filter_name="+category_url;
   $http({
     url: filterUrl,
     method: Config.endpoints.getMilestoneFilter.method
     
  }).success(function successCallback(response){
   switch(category_url) {
   case 'REGION': $scope.REGION = response.data;
    break;
   case 'SHIPPING_POINT': $scope.SHIPPING_POINT = response.data;
    break;
   }
  });
  
 }
 getFilterDataUrl('REGION');
 getFilterDataUrl('SHIPPING_POINT');
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">REGION:</label>
  <multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true" ng-model="REGION" options="i in REGION"
   change="selected()"></multiselect>
 </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">SHIPPING POINT:</label>
  <multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true" ng-model="SHIPPING_POINT" options="i in SHIPPING_POINT"
   change="selected()"></multiselect>
 </div>
```

But when I try to use this `$scope.REGION` or `$scope.SHIPPING_POINT`, I am getting "undefined". Whereas inside the success function, I am able to get the value. Please help me to understand what I did wrong in getting these scope values outside the `getFilterDataUrl()` function

Comment: use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`

Comment: Nope. Still not working

Comment: When are you trying to access these variables? Before or after the complete callback has fired? Those variables will not be populated until after the success callback fires.

Answer (score -1):

Define $scope.REGION and $scope.SHIPPING_POINT at the start of js.